# How to find all entities whose linked collection of entities contains at least one element from my list?

Tags: java, hibernate, querydsl

I want to find all entities `Foo`, whose `Bar` linked entities (via many-to-many relation) contains at least one element from my input `Set`.

```
@Override
public Set<Foo> findFoosHavingAtLeastOneBar(Set<Bar> bars) {
    QFoo foo = QFoo.foo;

    Predicate predicate = foo.bars. //I'm stuck here

}
```

When doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> I can't find anything that could help me achieve this.

Is it possible to do that in a single Hibernate request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract set of foo from your input bars and then add all the sets from there to another set to remove duplicates.

Comment: This looks totally valid, I didn't think about this approach at all... Didn't try it yet but this works for sure

Comment: Thanks for the insight!